# Netbeans autocomplete with namespaced abstract class

Tags: php, netbeans, intellisense

I have this abstract class

```
namespace Domain\Entities;

abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    protected $id;

    public function setId($id)
    {
        if(isset($this->id))
        {
            throw new Exception('ID already set.');
        }

        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Then in another class I do:

```
use Domain\Entities\AbstractEntity;

class MyClass extends AbstractEntity
{
    public function __constrcuct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

The problem is that NetBeans doesn't pick up the AbstractEntity. If I ctrl+click on the `AbstractEntity` in `class MyClass extends AbstractEntity` no information about AbstractEntity is presented.

Also, as I start typing `$this->id` in `MyClass` it should suggest members, but nothing comes up.

If I change MyClass to `class MyClass extends Domain\Entities\AbstractEntity` then it works.

Why doesn't it work with the `use` keyword? I'm using Netbeans 7.4 on Windows.

Comment: Same problem here, maybe this is fixed in 8.0.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in netbeans 8.0.

Comment: It still seems to happen in 8.0. It might be worth mentioning that the abstract class is in a different file, but I don't think that should matter. @Debflav can you show me the code you're using?

Comment: OK it does seem to work when I do up a basic example in 8.0, so there must be something wrong with my code :\

Comment: I've more or less the same structure as you. Maybe it's a bug in Netbeans 7.4. If you can do it, just upgrade your netbeans version.

Comment: OK so my issue was that I accidentally declared the namespace _after_ the use keywords in 'My Class'. It needs to be at the very top, whoops. It now works in both 7.4 and 8.0